# How to understand poles and zeroes intuitively?

Tags: laplace-transform, graph-laplacian

I am currently studying root locus method to analyze the stability of a given system which depends mostly on the poles of a given characteristic equation. However for better understanding I want to know intuitively or graphically about poles and zeroes of the equation .

Answer (score -1):

Just keep at it, & *cast* & *revolve* it in your mind, & constantly strive to discern the underlying *meaning* of what you are at: and after a while the picture *will* clarify & consolidate itself, & the essential gorgeous underlying *simplicity* of it will blaze forth upon your inner vision.